# Where() method and many to many relationship with the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables in my DataBase which are Video and Tags.
The Video table has three fields : Name, ID and a list of Tags.
The Tags table has two fields : tagName, tagID.

```
VideoViewModel model = new VideoViewModel
{
    Videos = repository.GetVideos
                        .Where(v => v.Name.Contains("Apple"))
};
```

Now let's say I've multiple videos where there is Apple in the name but only one of these which has Green as it's Tags.TagName how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `Videos` defined in the `dbContext` as `db`, try this

```
var result = db.Videos.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Apple"))
                      .Where(x => x.Tags.Count(y => y.tagName.Equals("Green")) == 1);
```